# Java returning an Object

Tags: java, object, return

Im currently learning Java and Im now facing the following error

```
Object label1 = addLabel("First number");
```

And my addLabel function

```
public Object addLabel(String text)
{
     JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
     add(label);

     return label;
}
```

I was wondering why I cant access any of the methods of label on my variable label1 if Im returining it as an object?

Ex : `label1.setBounds(...);`

Comment: Because the class `Object` (which is the type you are returning) does not have any of those methods. If you want JLabel methods, you need to make your object a JLabel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only access the methods that the variable has available, and Object has none of those methods. That is why you should not be using Object in this way. Yes, the object the variable holds is a JLabel, but the compiler knows that the variable can hold an object of **any** type, and so to be safe, only allows Object method calls.

Possible solutions:

- you can cast: `((JLabel) label1).setText("Foo");`
- Or better to declare `label1` as a JLabel variable and declare `addLabel` to return a JLabel.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have erased the type, you need to return a `JLabel` to use it as a `JLabel` -

```
public JLabel addLabel(String text)
{
  JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
  add(label);

  return label;
}
```

and then

```
JLabel label1 = addLabel("First number");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the type of object that exists in memory, and the type of reference you have to it.

In this case, your object in memory is a JLabel, but your reference is an Object - so code using this reference can only see methods available in Object.

If you chose to return your object as a JLabel and store the reference as a JLabel, your subsequent code would have access to the methods in JLabel.